# How do I sum one column within a grouping of another column?

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is my problem:

```
NAME    DATE           PRESENTS
bob     march 3 2011      1
bob     june 6 2008       2
bob     jan 3 2012        3
mary    feb 14 1986       4
mary    april 10 2001     5
mary    jan 3 2012        6
kate    march 3 2011      7
kate    jan 3 2012        8
kate    oct 9 2013        9
celia   march 3 2011     10
celia   feb 14 1986      11
celia   july 4 2011      12
celia   jan 3 2012       13
celia   feb 14 1991      14
```

So the goal is that we add the amount of presents Kate and Celia got on the same days if they received any at all on those days.

What I need to do is kind of like this, except with a much bigger data set. The size of the data set is probably around 100,000 entries.

I need the answer in SQL, or as an Access 2003 query.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: naming a column 'PRESENTS' when it's clearly an id is an example of bad design..

Comment: Please don't post homework-style questions. People will be more inclined to help you if you show them what you tried and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

If `presents` is the number of presents kate or celia or somepne else got on a particular date:

```
select name, date, sum(presents) total_on_date
from table
where name in ('kate','celia')
group by name, date
```

<sub>and I by no means am an sql genius</sub>

Comment: PRESENTS is *not* the amount of presents, it's an id

Comment: @ascanio I did suspect. But I assume that presents is the no of presents for that date for a preson, and the example OP has given is just an example (though not very apt)

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, date, count(presents) total_on_date
from table
where name in ('kate','celia')
group by name, date
```

assuming you want to count the presents ids

Answer (score 0):

You have to join back to itself, like this:

```
select DATE, SUM(PRESENTS) as TOTAL_JOINT_PRESENTS
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t1.DATE = t2.DATE
where t1.NAME = 'kate'
and t2.NAME = 'celia';
```

Answer (score 0):

related to answer given by Bohemian :-

I think in question he wants to calculate the days in which these both person came...

```
select count(*)
from mytable t1 join mytable t2 
     on t1.DATE = t2.DATE 
where t1.NAME = 'kate' and t2.NAME = 'celia';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want

> the amount of presents kate and celia got on the same days

then:

```
SELECT
    presents1.date AS presents_date,
    (COUNT(*) + 1) AS presents_count
FROM
    presents presents1,
    presents presents2
WHERE presents1.date = presents2.date
AND presents1.name = 'kate'
AND presents2.name = 'celia'
GROUP BY presents1.date
```

Asuming the table name is `presents`.