# Doing a calculation between two rows with EXTRA CRITERIA?

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
Name      ExactDate  Presents      Location
bob1         2011        1          home
bob2         2008        2          school     
bob2         2012        3          school
mary2        1986        4          school       
mary1        2001        5          home
mary1        2012        6          home    
kate1        2011        7          home
kate1        2012        8          home
kate2        2011        9          school 
celia2       2011       10          school 
celia2       1986       11          school  
celia1       1972       12          home
celia1       2012       14          home 
celia2       2012       13          school
```

This problem is done in SQL in MS Access 2003 for a query.

So the goal is we subtract the amount of presents kate got from celia on the same year ( but since there are a few different present values for the same year we choose to have priority of home > school....for example celia and kate both receive presents in 2012 but celia gets both home presents and school presents in 2012 in which case we choose her home present value to do the calculation) and out put should be something like the following:

```
Name              ExactDate        PresentsDiff
celiaminuskate     2011                      3
celiaminuskate     2012                      6
```

So far I have :

```
SELECT 'celiaminuskate'AS [NAME],T1.[date] AS [EXACT DATE],
T1.presents T2.presents AS [PRESENTS DIFF]
FROM Some_Table T1, Some_Table T2
```

part that I think needs to be fixed??

```
WHERE (T1.Name = 'celia1'>'celia2')
AND (T2.Name = 'kate1'>'kate2')
AND T2.ExactDate = T1.ExactDate
```

to indicate priority? I'm not too sure how to do it

```
ORDER BY T1.ExactDate
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between values in two rows of one table using MS Access 2003 SQL? with EXTRA CRITERIA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750282/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-values-in-two-rows-of-one-table-using-ms)

Comment: If this is homework, it should be tagged as homework. Here's another copy of the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722805/how-do-i-sum-one-column-within-a-grouping-of-another-column

Comment: Hey that was my question but now there is an extra "criteria" added to it that makes it a lot more difficult

Comment: It is not homework. it is work work.  so its like waht i ahve to do at work cept i changed all the values and actual data cuz of confidentiality  but the actual query woudl work the same . thanks

Comment: i do data management at work. but im a student and still in school yes and i am a begineer in sql and access with lots to learn. googling as i comment

Comment: All three questions have the same sample data set and the one I found was not posted by you, so I thought it was a homework question. But I guess it is not a coincidence that the one I found was also posted by a "Lizzy". My apologies.

Comment: I had to make up some fake values for he actual data i use at work thats why lets suppose this instead: celia1= amount of presents mom and dad think she got vs celia 2=  amount of presents friends think she got. and we think what the parents think is prolly more accurate than what the friends think so when there are two seperate values for the same year ( counted by friends vs family) we choose the parents cuz we belive it to be mroe accurate but if only friends prediction is available we use friends for the calculation. (so parents vs friends instead of school vs home. ) Does this make sense?

Comment: ya >.> and ops lol nice catching me there lol . i hope someone will be able to answer this . or maybe i should split it into two queries ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this query and saved it as qryCeliaAndKateGiftDates.  It just returns the distinct ExactDate values for which celia and kate both had gifts recorded.

Notice I re-named your *Name* field to *Recipient*, because *Name* is a reserved word.

```
SELECT DISTINCT celia.ExactDate
FROM
    [SELECT ExactDate
    FROM Some_Table
    WHERE Recipient Like "celia*"
    ]. AS celia
    INNER JOIN [
        SELECT ExactDate
        FROM Some_Table
        WHERE Recipient Like "kate*"
        ]. AS kate
    ON celia.ExactDate = kate.ExactDate
ORDER BY celia.ExactDate;
```

Then I used correlated subqueries to return the correct Presents values for celia and kate on each of those ExactDates.

```
SELECT
    raw.recipients AS [NAME],
    raw.ExactDate  AS [EXACT DATE],
    (raw.celia_presents - raw.kate_presents) AS [PRESENTS DIFF]
FROM
    [SELECT
    'celiaminuskate' AS recipients,
    dates.ExactDate,
    (SELECT TOP 1 Presents
    FROM Some_Table
    WHERE
        Recipient Like "celia*"
        And ExactDate = dates.ExactDate
    ORDER BY Location) AS celia_presents,
    (SELECT TOP 1 Presents
    FROM Some_Table
    WHERE
        Recipient Like "kate*"
        And ExactDate = dates.ExactDate
    ORDER BY Location) AS kate_presents
    FROM qryCeliaAndKateGiftDates AS dates]. AS raw;
```

It returns the results you requested when run from Access 2003.  However correlated subqueries are notoriously slow, so I'll be interested to see what other answers you get.

Comment: hey i was wondering you know how u use "-" to subtract. so can you also use "+" to add? ive tried that and instead of adding the values together it does this   123+0.28=1230.28    is does that maybe have anythign to do with the number being in text format? but i hadnt ever changed format from when i used "-" and that worked . Thank you

Comment: nope its all good nwo as you already kno lol thanks yet agian =).... i need to stop typing so terribly...